# How to rewrite URLs using mod_rewrite in .htaccess files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Are there any good, clear references for how to use mod_rewrite to change URLs?**

I'm trying to do a basic URL rewrite and when I try to figure it out, I find a million questions from people struggling with this and lots of random examples, but no single resource that just *explains how it works* and what all the options are, etc. Sometimes I get lucky and find something similar to what I'm trying to do, but often there are many different versions. Sometimes they all work. Sometimes none of them do. So it's a guessing game.

I found the [apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation but it reads like cheap stereo instructions. (Just a jumble of details and examples with no clear relationship) So I'm still guessing about many things.

I'll include what I'm trying to do in case it's an easy answer, but I'd rather RTFM so I can figure it out myself next time:

example.com/hideme/* --> example.com/*
(Hide a specific sub directory)

Comment: I've always observed that the biggest problem is the concept of how a URL is handled from the browser to the webserver (and at the webserver's handling of the URI, what role mod_rewrite plays). Because the notion of "changing a URL from X to Y" doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: That's exactly my biggest problem... What DOES make sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
# security requirement
Options +FollowSymlinks

# turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine on

# you only need to do those directives above once per .htaccess

# remap example.com/ w/ or w/o slash in the end into example.com/hideme/
RewriteRule ^/?$ /hideme/

# remap example.com/$group into example.com/hideme/$var
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /hideme/$1

# redirect example.com/hideme w/ or w/o slash in the end into example.com/
RewriteRule ^hideme/?$ / [R]

# redirect example.com/hideme/$group into example.com/$var
RewriteRule ^hideme/(.+)$ /$1 [R]
```

Actually, I didn't know if there's a mistake on the code above, that's why programmers always test what they've do, and if it work, they are done and no need to compare their codes into other codes what's better. This is one of my favorite instructions, and I think the easiest: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

---

**Additional Links:**

http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/mod_rewrite-quick-reference-and-cheat-sheet is I often visited when I'm looking for such `mod_rewrite` pattern syntax, `RewriteCond` operators and more.

Comment: That looks like a great link. I'll have a look. Something I've always wanted in particular is a clear explanation of the RewriteRule directive syntax. I tend to think of it like a regular expression search/replace but I don't think that's quite correct.

Comment: @Emerson Check my added links.

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` dir to hide dir `_wp`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+_wp/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

# assuming your cake installation is in /tests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^tests/)^(.*)$ /_wp/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will remove `/_wp` from the URL.

btw [**there is a book on mod_rewrite**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595610) as well other than those helpful Google search results.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify the part about R=302?

Comment: `R=302` means do a rewrite of URL with status=302. If you just want to do internal forward (no rewrite of URL) then flags should be: `NC,L`.

Comment: I forgot to ask, where should that .htaccess file go? The root above hidme ?

Comment: Yes it should go to DOCUMENT_ROOT dir which I believe is parent dir of `hideme`.

Comment: Does it matter if I have other .htaccess files in sub directories? I'm currently working on a cakePHP project which users and htaccess in the  hideme/app/webroot/ and also I think in the hideme/app. I'm not sure how multiple files interact.

Comment: Also just to make sure we're on the same page... I should be able to visit example.com/directory/ and see the contents of example.com/hideme/directory. Right?

Comment: ` I should be able to visit example.com/directory/ and see the contents of example.com/hideme/directory.` This wasn't clear from your question and it will require me to add another rule to my answer. Pls check the edit.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not getting it to work. Should it still be in the root directory? And should I be concerned about cake's htaccess file lower down? Basically, cake redirects everything to it's /hideme/app/webroot/index.php

Comment: When you enter this URL in browser: `http://example.com/hideme/directory` is it not becoming `http://example.com/directory` ?

Comment: Correct. I'm pasting in my complete .htaccess: `#
#THIS ALLOWS US TO OMIT wsat2!...
#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wsat2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wsat2/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wsat2/$1 [L]





#
#this should hide the wsat2 if included
#
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^wsat2/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wsat2/$1 [L]
`

Comment: Pls post your complete .htaccess in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` in your question and let me verify everything.

Comment: Would it be easier to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27797/discussion-between-anubhava-and-emerson)

Comment: I have created a new question to address the specific issue that you've been helping me with. My situation is described more clearly there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869240/how-to-make-cakephp-2-x-in-sub-directory-appear-in-root-with-mod-rewrite-in-hta

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I provided an answer on your new question.