# How to make cakePHP 2.x in sub directory appear in root (with mod_rewrite in htaccess)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on an cake app which is inside a sub directory (because I need to run it along side another app on the same domain). I want the pages powered by cake to appear as if they'r e top level.

So instead of `example.com/cake_dir/page...` I want `example.com/page...`

I think the best way to make this work is by adding a rewrite rule to an .htaccess file, so here's what I want to know:

1. Is this the best way to do this?
   If so:
2. What is the proper syntax for that kind of rule?
3. Where should that file go? The domain root? In the cake_dir? Or in cake's webroot?
4. If one of Cake's .htaccess files already exists in that location, should the new rule go before or after and should and of the `[L]`s be removed?

**UPDATE: Clearer description of what I'm trying to do**

```
example.com/ <--root
    /_cake   <--CakePHP installed here
        /page3
        /page4
```

Currently, visitors have to access page 3 by going to example.com/_cake/page3. This sucks. Instead I want this: example.com/page3 and if cake routes to example.com/_cake/page4 I want it to appear as example.com/page4 in the browser.

I've been cramming as much mod_rewrite knowledge as possible and I think the way to do this is to do an internal rewrote to show the correct content when the _cake is absent, and an external rewrite for when _cake IS present.

**Update**
Here are the existing .htaccess files...

.htaccess in /_cake...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in /_cake/app...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in /_cake/app/webroot...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php #[QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**Update 2**
I added anubhava's code to the root .htaccess file, and then also updated the .htaccess file at /_cake/ to look like the following (notice that I had to remove the [L]s in order for CakePHP's normal rewrites to still work):

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /_cake/page to /page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+_cake/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302]

# internal forward from /page to /_cake/page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^_cake/)^(.*)$ /_cake/$1 [NC]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### $DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# internal forward from /page to /_cake/page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^_cake/)^(.*)$ /_cake/$1 [L,NC]
```

#### $DOCUMENT_ROOT/_cake/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /_cake/
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

#### $DOCUMENT_ROOT/_cake/app/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /_cake/app/
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

#### $DOCUMENT_ROOT/_cake/app/webroot/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /_cake/app/webroot/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+_cake/([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still see _cake in the URL. Should it get removed?

Comment: Yes. Cake places an .htacces file in _cake and also in _cake/app/webroot. Are those applying because the external rewrite points back to the same domain?

Comment: I'm going to add each .htaccess file to the question...

Comment: Do you mean rename the directory? Or change the _cake in your code?

Comment: I did a search/replace with your code and it DOES change urls that contain /_sample/page to /page. Does this mean CakePHP's .htaccess is screwing things up?

Comment: AHA! I added a slightly modified version of your code to `/_cake/` and it's starting to work as expected (see my update2 above).

Comment: Everything seems to be working great. The only remaining issue is that my cake homepage still shows the /_cake/ (example.com/_cake/)

Comment: The rule now matches example.com/_cake/ but it redirects to / and I get a 404 forbidden error.

Comment: No. That directory is currently empty besides my _cake and _wp directories. Also, I need to correct the fact that our new rules cause CakePHP to look for /js/... and /css/... files in the wrong place. My understanding of everything we're doing is shaky, but I think we need to make rules to find those directories where they actually live (in _cake/app/webroot/)

Comment: example.com/_cake/ is now example.com/ ! I think the only problem left is the /css/ and /js/ directories.

Comment: This is what CakePHP is looking for `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_cake/css/cake.generic.css" />` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_cake/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It didn't work. Also, I noticed that now I get a redirect loop error at the document root.

Comment: Are you free to chat for a minute?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27891/discussion-between-anubhava-and-emerson)

Comment: Hello, getting 404 after apply this rule !!! please help

Comment: @mamun0024: Please open a new question with all the details as this is very old answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it so when someone requests `http://example.com/page` they actually get served the content provided by `/cake_dir/page`, then you should add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root (or "domain root"):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cake_dir%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cake_dir/$1 [L]
```

The URL in the browser's address bar will remain unchanged because there is no external redirect. The condition here is that it checks if the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cake_dir%{REQUEST_URI}` points to a file. That string essentially puts together the document root, then the string "cake_dir", then the actual requested file. In the case that none of these requests actually point to physical files in the "cake_dir", you can try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cake_dir/$1 [L]
```

Here, the conditions are that the requested URI (e.g. `/page`) does *not* point to an existing file or directory. And it routes everything blindly into the `/cake_dir` directory.

---

To *redirect* the browser in the event that someone clicks on a link with **cake_dir** in it, then you need these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /cake_dir/
RewriteRule ^cake_dir/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: YES!!!!! It worked after adding the second code block. I currently have them both. Is that correct? Also, is there a way to make it so that links within cake don't add the /cake_dir/ back into the url? Maybe a redirect?

Comment: @Emerson You only need one or the other, it just depends on what type of condition you want, whether the requested URI actually exists in the cake_dir (first) or whether a request doesn't match any physical file or directory (second).

Comment: Didn't quite understand the last bit. Can it be done so that the cake_dir never appears (even when in the original?

Comment: I'm close to getting this to work, but it's not quite right yet. I want example.com/cakepage to show content from example.com/cake_dir/cakepage and also all traffic to example.com/cake_dir/page to appear as example.com/page. I think the latter requires an "external" rewrite but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I updated the question with a clearer description.